# How to configure secureCRT to remove content display after quit from vim

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Open a ssh or telnet connection in secureCRT 6.0 or 7.0, when "vim xxx.txt", after quit vim by ":q", the content of xxx.txt will still be visible in screen. But in putty, the same operation, content of xxx.txt will be disappear. How to configure secureCRT to be like putty?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://forums.vandyke.com/showthread.php?t=3431), adding the following code into `.vimrc` works for me:

```
if &term =~ "xterm"
    " SecureCRT versions prior to 6.1.x do not support 4-digit DECSET
    "     let &t_ti = "\<Esc>[?1049h"
    "     let &t_te = "\<Esc>[?1049l"
    " Use 2-digit DECSET instead
    let &t_ti = "\<Esc>[?47h"
    let &t_te = "\<Esc>[?47l"
endif
```

For more information regarding the two variables `ti` and `te`, you can refer to `:help xterm-screens` in Vim